# uipickerview not displaying data with number of rows>0

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have made 4 pickerviews each has 15 objects,i implemented all the delegate methods.Returned 1 in number of components,number of rows is also correct,but in view for row method row is always 0 and pickerview is not diplayed.help me in finding where i am wrong.
Here is my code

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
     NSLog(@"In Number Of Components Method\n");
     int numberOfComponents = 1;
     return numberOfComponents; 
}


-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent(NSInteger)component {
    NSMutableArray* keysArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray* valuesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    DBManager* dbManger = [[DBManager alloc] init];
    //companyName,city,category,postalCode
    NSInteger count = 0;
    switch (pickerView.tag) {
        case 0:
            if (![selectBusinessTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
                [keysArray addObject:@"category"];
                [valuesArray addObject:selectBusinessTextField.text];
            }
            if (![selectCityTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
                [keysArray addObject:@"city"];
                [valuesArray addObject:selectCityTextField.text];
            }
            if (![selectPostalCodeTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
                [keysArray addObject:@"postalCode"];
                [valuesArray addObject:selectPostalCodeTextField.text];
            }

            if (keysArray.count) {
                alternateArrayFoBusinessNamesArray = [dbManger fetchColumn:@"companyName" whereKeysAre:keysArray andValuesAre:valuesArray];
            else
                alternateArrayFoBusinessNamesArray = [dbManger fetchColumn:@"companyName"];
            }

            count = alternateArrayFoBusinessNamesArray.count;
            break;
    } 
    return count;
}

-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

    UILabel* pickerItemLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, textFieldWidth, 40)];
    [pickerItemLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:appFontBold size:18]];
    [pickerItemLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    switch (pickerView.tag) {
        case 0:
        {
            NSString* name = [alternateArrayFoBusinessNamesArray objectAtIndex:row];
            [pickerItemLabel setText:[alternateArrayFoBusinessNamesArray objectAtIndex:row]];
        }
        break;
        case 1:
            [pickerItemLabel setText:[citiesNamesArray objectAtIndex:row]];
            break;
        case 2:
            if ([[businessTypesArray objectAtIndex:0]isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
                [pickerItemLabel setText:[businessTypesArray objectAtIndex:row]];
            else
                [pickerItemLabel setText:[businessTypesArray objectAtIndex:row]];
        break;
        case 3:
            [pickerItemLabel setText:[postalCodesArray objectAtIndex:row]];
        break;
    }
    return pickerItemLabel;
}
```

Comment: You would have to provide some code in order for the community to help you, please provide the implementation of the picker view.

Comment: Please add the code you are using

Comment: Your implementation would be helpful.

Comment: I dont see any number return in `-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent(NSInteger)component` method. Your compiler should be showing some error surely.

Comment: no it always return 15 ,and enters the method view for row,but cycle run only once

Comment: You have 3 `UIPickerView`? Are your picker visible?

Comment: none of the pickerview is visible

Comment: You do realise that you will only return a non zero count for picker view with `tag == 0`?

Comment: i pasted only 1 case

Comment: Did you add your pickerView as subView?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was problem,every thing was fine except,the size of pickerview. which i set 0,as in older ios versions (<9.0) pickerview height was fixed to 0 and it defaults to 216 ,and now it is adjustable ,so giving 0 meaning 0 not 216.

[iOS 9 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-9.0/)

> "UIPickerView and UIDatePicker are now resizable and
>   adaptive—previously, these views would enforce a default size even if
>   you attempted to resize them. These views also now default to a width
>   of 320 points on all devices, instead of to the device width on
>   iPhone."

So i changes it to some size and every thing is working fine